# Python TreeStructure (parent and children) class, children gets appended to it's own children?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parent, parent-child, tree-structure

I'm coding a `TreeStructure` (TS) class, which lets me create parent and child objects, which are linked to each other. Every TS -object has `m_parent` attribute, which is controlled with `parent` property, and also they have `children` list, which holds in all the children of this parent. Whenever I add a child to it's parent's `children` list, it gets added to it's own `children` list too? Here's what I have:

```
ROOT = "__ROOT__"

class TreeStructure:

    def __init__(self, parent=ROOT, children=[]):
        self.children = children
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def parent(self):
        '''Returns m_parent'''
        if hasattr(self, "m_parent"):
            return self.m_parent
        else:
            return None

    @parent.setter
    def parent(self, parent=ROOT):
        '''Sets m_parent'''
        if type(parent) == type(self):
            if self.parent:
                del self.parent
            self.m_parent = parent
            self.m_parent.children.append(self)
        elif parent == ROOT:
            if self.parent:
                del self.parent
            self.m_parent = ROOT
        else:
            raise TypeError("Parent's type %s did not match objects type %s"
                            %(type(parent), type(self)))

    @parent.deleter
    def parent(self):
        '''Deletes m_parent'''
        if self.parent:
            if self.parent != ROOT:
                self.m_parent.children.remove(self)
            del self.m_parent
```

And now by creating two simple objects, it should work. However, it doesn't.

```
a = TreeStructure()
b = TreeStructure(a)
```

The problem appears at line 25, `self.m_parent.children.append(self)`. If I add print's to both sides of that line, I see that both `print(self.m_parent.children)` and `print(self.children)` print an empty list `[]` BEFORE the append line. Now if I add the prints AFTER the append line, both prints will say `[<__main__.TreeStructure object at 0x...>]`, which should only happen for the parent, not the child?

Comment: Having a default argument on a "setter" doesn't make any sense, as it's always called with both arguments. Also, checks like ``type(parent) == type(self)`` look pretty scary and make subclassing impossible. Wouldn't ``isinstance(parent, TreeStructure)`` suffice? Or even ``hasattr(parent, "children")``.

Comment: I don't quite get your point here, wouldn't `isinstance(parent, TreeStructure)` just prevent me from inheriting any classes off of TreeStructure, cause that check would only be true with the superclass? **Edit**: Hmm just tested it with a subclass, my object is instance of the subclass, but still isinstance(object, superclass) returns true... Kinda stupid imo. Also, I'm creating a Menu -class here, and I only want to add Menu object's to other Menu objects, not TreeStructures, even if the Menu inhertis from TS. And `hasattr` would be pretty dangerous.

Comment: In this case, I would probably make a separate method like ``can_contain`` for that check. In ``TreeStructure`` this would accept any subclass, then in ``Menu`` you can override it to accept only ``Menu`` subclasses. This way if you later create a ``FancyMenu`` class, you will be able to add it to the menu without having to change this code.

Comment: And that's a perfect idea. I'm still learning and can't really think of something like that :P Thanks for the quick-tip :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `[]` as a default value!

```
>>> def bad(default=[]):
...     default.append(1)
...     print default
... 
>>> bad()
[1]
>>> bad()
[1, 1]
>>> bad()
[1, 1, 1]
>>> def good(default=None):
...     if default is None:
...             default = []
...     default.append(1)
...     print default
... 
>>> good()
[1]
>>> good()
[1]
```

Default arguments are created when the function is *defined*, not when it is *called*.
So only use non-mutable types for defaults. using integers, strings, tuples is okay, but if you want a default list or dictionary or anything mutable then use `None` and do the above trick.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) question and answers for better understanding of this matter.

Comment: Woooah I've been using python for quite a lot, but didn't know this one, I've never really ran into the problem. But yeah thanks, I'm an inch more intelligent now :)

Comment: @Mahi: the way to detect this problem is by noticing `a.children is b.children == True`

Comment: Yeah I did detect the problem, just couldn't figure out why it happens, feeling stupid now :P

Answer (score -2):

You've been caught out by old-style classes (which don't support descriptors, such as `@property`s). You should be using:

```
class TreeStructure(object):
```

After doing that, your code works for me

#### EDIT:

I'm testing using python 2.7. In 3.x, all classes are new-style.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 3.2.3. That code shouldn't work for you either.

Comment: @Mahi: Yep, I was seeing an altogether different problem, where `children` was always `[]`. Added python 3.x as a tag, since it's important here.